# How to find out how many lines are there in a LiveCode datagrid

Tags: livecode

What can I do to know how many lines I have in my datagrid?

I have searched in the documentation and it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you count the keys of the dgData:

```
put the number of keys of the dgData of grp "My Data Grid" into myNumberOfRecords
```

Another possibility is

```
put the dgNumberOfRecords of grp "My DAta Grid" into myNumberOfRecords
```

and probably there are a few more possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you're looking for?

> Property `dgNumberOfLines`
>   Returns the number of lines displayed in the data grid.

[DataGrid API](http://lessons.runrev.com/m/datagrid/l/7344-data-grid-api)